# How to get option values in redux framework?

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I am using redux framework. I am not getting the any values that was I set in redbux framework backend.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You best head over to the Redux Framework docs. A good starter is the getting started page: http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/getting-started/

That should get you where you need to go.  :)

Comment: P.S. Lead dev of Redux here.  :)

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy to get redux option values.

Suppose `test_name` is the value of your `$opt_name`. Then you just need to use `$test_name['id']` to access the option value. It's all.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your **$opt_name** value is **rdx_option**

Now to access any Redux fields value you need to write :

global $rdx_option;

```
echo $rdx_option['id'];
```

Here in the place of '**id**' you have to give your Redux fields id name.